# Using close link in accordion content to change accordion icon

Tags: jquery

I'm not using jQuery UI for accordion. I wrote this quick script because jQuery UI is too bloated for what I need it for. I have setup a codepen with what I currently have, but I cannot get the close link within the content to change the src of the icon image in the header.

**Here's what my markup looks like**:

```
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h3 class="accordion-label">test <img src="http://placehold.it/25x25"/></h3>
      <div class="accordion-content">
         Lorem Ipsum
         <span class="close">close</span>  
      </div>
    </div>
```

**I'm trying to target the img tag in the h3 like this:**

```
  $(this).parent('.accordion-content').prev('h3').children('img').attr('src','http://placehold.it/25x25');
```

The result I'm trying to get is that when I click the "close" link in the content of the expanded accordion-content, I want the accordion-content to collapse and then change the image src to the collapsed icon (using placeholders for sake of testing here).

I'm using jQuery 2.0.

**CODEPEN:** http://codepen.io/cvanorman/pen/YXpBRJ

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       function profilesAccordion() {
       // Profiles Accordion
            $('.accordion-content').hide(); // Hide all Containers

            // Add 'active' class to first accordion item.
            $('.accordion-label').click(function() {
                $(this).siblings('.accordion-content').slideToggle();
                $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            });

            $('.close').click(function() {
                $(this).parent('.accordion-content').slideToggle();
                $(this).closest('.accordion-item').find('.accordion-label').removeClass('expanded');
            });

        } profilesAccordion();
   });
```

Comment: I've fixed the camelCasing on my end, but I'm not sure what you mean about it not working the way I want it to. I added the clickToggle script because jQuery deprecated .toggle() for this use.

Comment: oh when i was testing your script it was running clicktoggle at the beginning and i did it wrong, my bad. but on close you should just set the image to the one you want instead of click toggling, because you don't really need to toggle it (since when the user clicks close there is only one state the image can be)

Comment: Ah, I guess I could do that, sorry about the misunderstanding! I'll test it out in a second and let you know if that works.

Comment: instead of toggling on the image as well, you should probably make sure that it is really the image you want (check the source of the image or put a data attribute), because then otherwise the answer below works, its just because of all the toggling, while it seems it is the one you want, you're changing the flow since close would also set a new "toggle" state

Comment: The bottom code appears to be working with your suggested fix. The issue I have now is likely with  event propagation.

For instance, when I click the header to expand the content, then click on the 'close' link from the content, the img src updates to the right icon, but when the icon is pressed from the header again, it doesn't change until I make another click.

I'm relatively new to javascript, so I don't entirely understand eventPropagation.

Comment: well, basically every event happens (whether a click event, focusin, focusout, etc.) tells the parent "a [this event] happened"  and says run some functionality. which is why in many pieces of code you see "event.stopProprogation()/event.preventDefault()", its not what i'm talking about, its because you are toggling but you are not telling the toggle state i want to untoggle. its why toggling isn't really a good use in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(this).closest('.accordion-item').find('.accordion-label img').attr('src','http://placehold.it/25x25');
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working for me. If it works for you, please let me know which version of jQuery you're using. I'm currently using 2.0 locally and 2.1 in the codepen.

Answer (score 1):

The best functionality to do in this case: use a data-attribute to let you know what state the dom is currently and trigger that everytime you close/open the accordion (or you can use a class and then use before/after on the css and image-background). Its because if you put "close" then you would also change when the item should toggle.

Comment: Thank you, I'll rewrite this to have a data-attribute with the toggle state. I've accepted the answer below since that piece of code worked like I needed it to.

Comment: yup, that's fine. i only brought it out my answers from the comments because someone might look through your codepen and might be confused later on :P

Comment: I'll update my question with the working code. I ended up settling for adding an .expanded class and having that change the background of my h3.accordion-label. This also reduced my javascript a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes, its not answering what is asked but what you want to do and accomplish what you want to do and javascript logic can get complicated at times if you don't keep close tabs on it. but you're welcome, good luck with learning JS!